# Como usar BidingContext para vincular Views a um Dictionary?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Minha aplicação Xamarin tem como uma de suas caracteristicas, criar formulários baseados em um objecto.

Eu tenho tido problemas na hora de salvar os dados desse formulário. Eu tenho que percorrer os filhos do StackLayout pra então popular o `Dictionary<string, object>()`.

O que eu gostaria de fazer (e acredito ser a maneira mais correta de se fazer) é usar o databiding do Xamarin pra vincular os elementos do formulário com o `Dictionary<string, object>()` pra dessa forma evitar que eu precise percorrer a lista de elementos toda vez.

Como o formulário é criado dinamicamente, eu não faria o Biding pelo XAML, mas sim em algum momento que eu crio a view:

```
var entry = new 
        Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
    };
```

Eu só não sei se eu adiciono o Dictionary que eu tenho no meu ViewModel.

Comment: Sim. Ou você adiciona o Dictionary na view model ou vocÊ alimenta alguma outra classe (que você ainda teria que criar) para trabalhar com os valores informados.

Comment: O trecho de código está incompleto, mas deu para entender que vcoÊ está criando um `Entry`. Fazer o bind do entry com cada elemento do seu dicionário, acredito que resolverá seu problema.

Comment: O dicionário já precisaria estar com as chaves corretas pra que o bind saiba onde guardar a informação da `Entry` ?

Comment: Sim. O bind será feito para um elemento do dicionário, e não para o dicionário inteiro. Tipo, se você tem `Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();` o binding context para cada componente seria `dic["key"]` por exemplo.

Comment: Diego, essa resposta aqui era bem o que eu queria fazer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985634/xamarin-forms-databinding-separator Valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Ótimo! O ruim é que no XAML você tem que deixar os índices/chaves hardcoded, mas se não é um problema, beleza.